# createjs button mouse over not working

Tags: button, mouseevent, mouseover, createjs, mouseout

This is using a button on the stage in Flash CC 2014 in Canvas mode (html 5).
The button has a mouse over look on frame 2 of the button movie clip. I am using this code to go to the frame 2 of the button but it is not working:

```
function mouseOver(event) {
    // frame 2 the button is darker in tint
    event.currentTarget.gotoAndStop(2);
    stage.update(event); 
}
```

Comment: How are you assigning the mouseOver event handler?

Comment: I guess the main thing is that I am not getting timeline controls of a movie clip added to the stage. So the mouseover does work but when I access the button (movie clip) to go to a frame, it doesn't work.

'function mouseOver(event) {
 event.currentTarget.gotoAndStop(); // doesn't work
 stage.update(event); 
}'

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you need to enable the mouse over effect. For example:

```
var stage = new createjs.Stage("canvas");
stage.enableMouseOver(10);

// Draw circles
var c1 = new createjs.Shape().set({name:"large-purple"});
c1.graphics.f("purple").dc(100,100,75);
c1.addEventListener("mouseover", function(event) {
    c1.scaleX = c1.scaleY = 1.1;
});
c1.addEventListener("mouseout", function(event) {
    c1.scaleX = c1.scaleY = 1;
});
```

You need to use this function `stage.enableMouseOver(10);` to enable mouse events.

Comment: Why wouldn't all these events be enabled by default?  Why force people to go through so much pain (searching for a solution) for such a little thing?